# Is there a python coding method for reading the value of a GPIO pin

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

Recently I have been learning to prototype circuits on a couple devices, as I am inspired to one day design and develop embedded systems.

The two devices that I have been prototyping with are the AVR family of micro-controllers ,and of course, the raspberry-Pi3.

I program in C with AVR's and Python on the Pi. Python has been a lot  easier to learn, and for me, more intuitive, while with C I have had many struggles so far.

As C coding relates to pin/register manipulation though, I have of the AVR's "PIN" statement, which can read the stored value of a GPIO pin on the AVR.

Is there a an equivalent statement within a python library module which offers the same functionality.

Comment: Which version of python are you planning on using on the AVR microcontrollers? The standard versions will not work because they are too large. There is both MicroPython and CircuitPython available.

Comment: No, what I mean is I’m looking for a similar statement to “PIN” to use with Raspberry-Pi GPIO’s, using Python.

Comment: Start with the [gpiozero module](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)